# Receiving an entity depending on the current user id

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
      var user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
      var allCategories = db.ProfitCategories
          .Where(x => x.IdUser.UserId==user)
```

I want my Index view show only records that is written from current user. I get current userId from here

```
var user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
```

and  `x.IdUser.UserId` is a foreign key from `db.ProfitCategories` to `db.UserProfiles`. When compiling I get the following error: Can not apply operators `==` type  `int` and  `Models.UserProfiles`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should try:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
       var user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
       var allCategories = db.ProfitCategories
           .Where(x => x.IdUser.UserId==user.UserId)
```

You need to check UserId against UserId and not the class.

**Edit**

I think you don't have to get the user at all:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var allCategories = db.ProfitCategories
       .Where(x => x.IdUser.UserId==WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
```

Since you already have the user id saved in the `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` you don't need to receive the user from database (at least not for getting its Id). Of course, if you need it for other actions (which I can't know because you provided a just fragment of code), feel free to receive the user :)

Comment: yes you're right in your edit i Accept answer but don't have reputation for +1 .Sorry, Need 1 more reputation I will back to this post when I have :)